# Pass array from a function to main

Tags: c, arrays, function

How do I pass an array from a function to main in C?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int merge(int a[],int b[])
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;    
    int k=0;
    int c[17];
    while(i<10&&j<8)
    {
        if(a[i]<b[j])
        {

            c[k]=a[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            c[k]=b[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<10)
    {
        c[k]=a[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<10)
    {
        c[k]=b[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Also. Your question did not make sense. You want that your function return an array?

Comment: sir my moto is to combine 2 arrays and return the new array to the main function..

Comment: i hv made the indentations proper but somhow the codes are not readabe propperly on the site ..

Comment: You can pass pointers around quite easily. How is your attempt failing?

Comment: sorry for inconvinience..

Comment: I guess the `merge` method will _always_ overrun the `c` array, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, you are returning a pointer to something allocated on the stack. That's bad.

Comment: 1. Your array is local to the function it is declared in and references to it are invalid once the function returns.  2. You have declared the function to return an int, yet you are attempting to return a pointer to an int (you cannot return arrays from functions, they degrade to pointers).  3.  Your loops are unsafe, you have no idea how large the input arrays are.  4. This is a very confused question in general and your description is lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ideas...

1. You can't return arrays in C but you *can* return a `struct` that contains an array, so you could do that.
2. If you just say `int x[3]; return x;` that will return the address of `x.` That's OK if it's static or malloc-ed but will lose horribly if it's an ordinary auto-storage-class local.
   So whatever you do, you should `malloc(3)` the object in the function, or at least make it static.
3. You could pass the new array as a parameter, thus avoiding the issue of returning it.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to take *three* array parameters:

```
void merge(int a[], int b[], int c[]);
```

Then you can merge `a` and `b` and put the result into `c`. The person who calls the function is responsible for creating the array used as `c` to be large enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your function to return the array there are 2 ways:

1. The function has to return a pointer to the first item in the array (actually the array itself is a pointer in C). In this case your function must be declared as `int *merge(int a[], int b[])`.
2. You have to pass the array to the function that will be modified by the function itself. Here's how you can do this: `int merge(int A[], int B[], int C[])`.

Comment: No, no, no. Arrays are not pointers. They *decay* to pointers when passed around, but those are different datatypes.

Comment: @StoryTeller Good to know, I tought that it was a pointer to the first element of the array. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you are being sarcastic or not. But the definitive way to see the difference is to declare an array an print it's `sizeof`. Than do the same with a pointer. http://ideone.com/FR9win

Comment: You might also want to add a warning to option 1 that the returned pointer cannot point to a local variable.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm not being sarcastic but my professor said that arrays are basically pointers.

Comment: @ShadowBroker, that's alright than. Guess you also learned that you shouldn't *always* listen to your professors :)

Comment: @StoryTeller you're right i guess :) Also found more informations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers