# C++ pointer comparison with []operator for arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have been reading a [book](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Programming_In_Ansi_C.html?id=3fZa9af1KtYC&redir_esc=y) which says that accessing array elements by pointer arithmetic's is much faster than the [] operator. In short [this](http://ideone.com/qrbFbJ) code is faster than [this](http://ideone.com/OrbTZj) code.
The book does not say why. Is it advisible to use such pointer arithmetic's even if it provides significant improvement in speed?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    double *array = new double[1000000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;//slower?
    }
    delete[] array;
    return 0;
}

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    double *array = new double[1000000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        *(array + i) = 0;//faster?
    }
    delete[] array;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Quote from book pg 369, 2nd last line

> The pointer accessing method is much faster than array indexing.

Comment: Get away from that book as fast as possible.

Comment: Read a better book, basically.

Comment: Are thsoe examples actually from the book, or did you synthesize them? Oddly one `delete`s the array and the other doesn't...

Comment: @BeeOnRope the book is for C. It does not have this code, but the converted English into C++.

Comment: I didn't understand "but the converted English into C++"

Comment: DId you compile both with optimization on and compare the assembly code for both?

Comment: @BeeOnRope sorry typo. ""But I converted English from book into C++ code", please see the edit in question.

Comment: I see. Your example then doesn't really capture what the book is trying to say, since you are still using "indexing" in both examples. When they say pointer arithmetic might be faster they are talking about something like the examples given in my answer and woolstar's answer. In that case, the answer is more subtle than "they are identical according to the standard".

Comment: There was a paragraph of text before that line explaining the concept with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are exactly the same thing. I definitely suggest you to drop that book and [pick another one up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1) as soon as possible.

And even if there was any performance difference, the clarity of `x[12]` over `*(x + 12)` is much more important.

Answer (score 2):

Array indices are just syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic. Your compiler will boil down `a[i]` into `*((a) + (i))`. Agreed, run away from that book!

For more in-depth explanations, see

1. [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608421/3171324)
2. [Eli Bendersky's explanation](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference at all, if we go to the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `5.2.1` *Subscripting* paragraph *1* says (*emphasis mine*):

> [...]**The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))** [Note: see 5.3 and 5.7 for details of * and + and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. —end note ]

Answer (score 1):

Utter rubbish. `a[x]` on a plain array decays into `*(a + x)`. There will literally be 0 performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

The book is just plain wrong - especially if those are the actual examples they gave.  Decent compilers are likely to produce identical code for both methods, even without optimization and they will have identical performance.

Without optimization, or with compilers from the 80s, you might get performance differences with some types of pointer arithmetic, but the examples don't even represent that case. The examples are basically just different syntax for the same thing.

Here's an example that could plausibly have a performance difference (versus the array index case which is unchanged):

```
int main() {
  // your code goes here
  double *array = new double[1000000], *ptr = array;
  for(; ptr < array + 1000000; ptr++)
  {
    *ptr = 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here, you aren't indexing against the base pointer each time through the loop, but are incrementing the pointer each time. In theory, you avoid the multiplication implicit in indexing, resulting in a faster loop. In practice, any decent compiler can reduce the indexed form to the additive form, and on modern hardware the multiplication by `sizeof(double)` implied by indexing is often free as part of an instruction like `lea` (load effective address), so even at the assembly level the indexed version may not be slower (and may in fact be faster since it avoids a loop-carried dependency and also lends itself better to aliasing analysis).

Answer (score -1):

Your two forms are the same, you're not really doing pointer arithmetic.

The pointer form would be:

```
double * array= new double[10000000] ;
double * dp= array ;

for ( int i= 0 ; ( i < 10000000 ) ; i ++, dp ++ )
{
  * dp= 0 ;
}
```

Hear, the address in `dp` is moved to the next one via an add.  In the other forms, the address is calculated each go through the loop by multiplying `i` time sizeof(double) and adding it to `array`.  Its the multiply that historically was slower than the add.

Comment: Your loop never terminates.

Comment: Ah, looks like I went a little too fast.