# error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’?

Tags: c

My program should give me the length, the highest  and the lowest character of a word.
When I compile the program I get the error:

```
error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[64]’ [-Werror=format=]
         scanf("%62s", & cString);
```

It would be very nice, if somebody could me with this!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int stringstats(char sString[], char *cGroesster, char *cKleinster)
{
    //Variablen deklarieren

    int iLength = 0;
    int i = 0;
    *cKleinster = sString[0];
    *cGroesster = sString[0];

    while (sString[iLength] != '\0')
    {
        iLength++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= iLength - 1; i++)
    {
        if (sString[i] < *cKleinster)
        {
            *cKleinster = sString[i];
        }

        if (sString[i] > *cGroesster)
        {
            *cGroesster = sString[i];
        }
    }
    return iLength;
}

//Funktion deklarieren

int stringstats(char[], char *, char *);

#define LENGTH 64
int main(void)
{
    //Variablendeklaration

    char cString[LENGTH] = {0};
    int iLength = 0;
    char cGroesster = 0;
    char cKleinster = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        //Benutzereingabe String
        printf("Bitte einen String eingeben ('q' fuer Beenden) \n");
        scanf("%62s", & cString);

        //that`s where my problem is

        //Abbruchbedingung pruefen
        if (cString[0] == 'q' && cString[1] == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }

        //Funktion stringstats aufrufen
        iLength = stringstats(cString, &cGroesster, &cKleinster);

        printf("Laenge: %i \n", iLength);
        printf("Kleinster Buchstabe: %c \n", cKleinster);
        printf("Groesster Buchstabe: %c \n\n", cGroesster);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW: There is absolutely no use in adding a forward-declaration *after* the definition. Just leave it out.

Comment: @Deduplicator They may have been declared in separate source files, and he was properly including the other function because he thought it might have something to do with his problem.

Comment: @SevenBits: Quite possible. It's either not pruning the example quite enough, which happens easily, or an actual lack of understanding. Though I could not say which. Can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is a feature of C not known by most beginning programmers. That about what `scanf` wants: it wants a pointer to a `char`. While you are correct in using the reference of (&) operator to get a pointer to it, this is actually incorrect for this use because in C, arrays (including strings) are continuous blocks of memory **accessed by a pointer**, therefore, you do not use the reference-of operator.

Therefore, doing this:

```
scanf("%62s", & cString);
```

Is passing a pointer to a pointer to (that's not a typo) a `char` value. If the function expects a string, don't pass a reference to it.

Now, let's look at your error message. The compiler is giving you this:

```
format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[64]
```

What it's telling you is that *you do not have a string*. Rather, you have an array of pointers to a `char`.

Change:

```
char cString[LENGTH] = {0};
```

to:

```
char cString[LENGTH];
```

and change:

```
scanf("%62s", & cString);
```

to:

```
scanf("%62s", cString);
```

and that should fix your problem.

Comment: @remyabel Sorry, my bad. I'll fix the question.

Comment: @rowan.G I'm not being a dick, it's simply incorrect to say that "arrays are pointers", *especially* if the premise is about clearing up confusion for a beginner. Read [In C, are arrays pointers or used as pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers).

Comment: @rowan.G I agree with remyabel. In this case I had simply typed too fast, but in other cases, saying a wrong statement could have ramifications. On a site like this, you need to clear up people when they are wrong to prevent dissemination of false info, esp. to beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
  scanf("%62s", & cString);
```

with this:

```
  scanf("%62s", cString);
```

cString is already a pointer, as when you specify the array, that is implied. You were passing in the address of the pointer, which was a type of char**

Comment: Nope. `cString` is obviously **not a pointer**. Want to re-read the error-message or the code and try again?

Comment: What @Deduplicator said, that's not a string. Look closer.