# Trying to input values and print them out in a matrix using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I am trying to input values into a 3x3 matrix using pointers instead of using index. Below is my main program:

```
int main() {
 int mat[ROW][COL];
 int *p = &mat[0][0];

 minput(p, ROW, COL);

 return 0; 
}
```

And this is my minput function:

```
void minput(int *m, int row, int col) {
  // 1 2 3
  // 4 5 6
  // 7 8 9

 *(m+0) = 1;

}
```

What I cant figure out is how to input the rest of the matrix, like [1][1]. I tried `*(*(p+1)+1)` to try and access m[1][1] but it didnt seem to work. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `minput` function, you can access `mat[i][j]` by `*(m+i*col+j)`

Also check [In C, are arrays pointers or used as pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers), very useful