# Is this a pointer to a pointer of the start of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointer-to-pointer

I've just been helping someone out with some code. He had this:

```
char dataArray[10];
```

Then wanted to get a pointer to the start of the array. Rather than use:

```
&dataArray[0]
```

or just

```
dataArray
```

He used

```
&dataArray
```

Did he end up with a pointer to a pointer there? I'm not sure what `&dataArray` would give him.

Comment: no, that's a pointer-to-array. its exact type is `char (*)[10]`, a. k. a. pointer-to-array-of-10-`char`s. By the way, http://cdecl.org…

Comment: So, if that &dataArray is passed to a function that is expecting a pointer to a char, the compiler should give a warning? In this particular instance if you incremented the pointer, the address should increment by ten?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 9):

- `&dataArray[0]` is of type `char *`. That is a pointer to `char`.
- `dataArray` is of type `char[10]`
- `&dataArray` will be of type `char (*)[10]`. That is a pointer-to-array.

Apart from that, the *value* will be same, i.e., they point to the same address but their types need not be compatible.

None of them is a *pointer-to-pointer* here. They are just pointer with different types.

<sup>Note: Because the array decaying property, `char [100]` will decay to a `char *`, for example, when passed as an agument of a function.</sup>

Comment: is `dataArray` not also a correct representation of pointer to array?

Comment: @ryyker Updated my answer. Please have a look :-)

Comment: _None of them is a pointer-to-pointer here. They are just pointer with different types_ is the key phrase that clearly summarizes the bullet points you provide in your response.  Good clarification.

Comment: I'm well aware that &dataArray[0] and dataArray are the same - and both pointers to a char, I as much as said it in the original post. :) I'm still not sure of whether the compiler should have given a warning or error because he was passing, what I now believe to be a pointer to an array, rather than a pointer to a char. Also, in this particular instance if you incremented the pointer to the array as this is, the address should increment by ten because it's an array of ten chars?

Comment: @DiBosco No, that is wrong. ` &dataArray[0]` and `dataArray` are not the same. The former is the pointer to the first element of the array `dataArray`, whereas the second is the array itself. **An array is NOT a pointer!!!**

Comment: Really? I've often seen the two as interchangeable and that claim goes directly against what others have said here!

Comment: @DiBosco Yeah, really. Go read the standard. "An array is often implicitly converted to a pointer" is not the same as "an array is a pointer". Also, try printing the result of `sizeof(dataArray)` and `sizeof(&dataArray[0])`. And read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers).

Comment: "Apart from that, the value will be the same" should rather read: "they point to the same address... `&dataArray[0]` and `&dataArray` need not be compatible.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you sir for the advice, makes perfect sense, updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

dataArray and &dataArray[0] points to the address of the first index of the array so they are the same thing but &dataArray will point to the address of the whole array or we can say it will give the address where the whole 10 index array is located(as a whole)