# In C language, What is the difference between extern buffer[] and extern *buffer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I read the below piece of information in a microsoft article;

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/44463

> The text below presents an example of a common programming mistake, that is, confusing an array and a pointer declaration:
>   Consider an application divided into several modules. In one module, declare an array as follows:
>
> ```
>   signed char buffer[100];
> ```
>
> In another module, declare the following variables to access the array:
>
> ```
>  extern signed char *buffer;           // FAILS  
>  extern signed char buffer[];          // WORKS
> ```
>
> If you view the code in the CodeView debugger, it indicates that the `*buffer` declaration produces a different address than the `buffer[]` declaration does.

1. But I can't understand why we cannot access that array using `*buffer`
   and we can access it using `buffer[]` .
2. Someone please explain me what is the difference between those two types?

Comment: This has to be a duplicate

Comment: I've always used them interchangeably.  Getting different addresses makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Isaiah  [A good read](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30892206/2173917)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: differences between char pointer and array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array)

Comment: Ok, pointers and arrays ARE NOT THE SAME. You're trying to tell the compiler to look for a pointer when its an array

Comment: It's not too humble, but I would reference [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533439/string-literals-vs-array-of-char-when-initializing-a-pointer) especially the accepted answer to it.

Comment: In a nutshell: dereferencing a pointer is **one more indirection** than accessing an array. Code using the pointer declaration (when the identifier is an array) bombs because of the extra indirection. There's a super clear explanation of exactly this in Peter van der Linden's *"Expert C Programming - Deep C Secrets"*.

Comment: @Isaiah, You're right, and I do understand how to be careful with them.  Does the different addresses comment puzzle you?

Comment: No, An array begins at the first location and ends at the last location, all contigious. A pointer lives in one location that stores the address of another location which could be completely different. @donjuedo

Comment: Can you please elaborate it @Isaiah

Comment: Can you please tell me the page number where the topic is found @Jens

Comment: @Isaiah, Yes, I understand that part.  But both declarations are `extern`, so I'd expect both to link to the same symbol, and therefore same address.  That's what I have trouble with.

Comment: @RelevationsSajith Chapter 4, **The Shocking Truth: C Arrays and Pointers Are NOT the Same!**, page 95pp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these questions in the C FAQ List:

- http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr1.html
- http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html
- http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html

Comment: That Solved my problem!Thanks a lot Steve.+1 for your link.

Answer (score 4):

```
extern signed char buffer[];
```

is a chunk of memory that **has** an address.

```
extern signed char *buffer;
```

is a variable that **may or may not point to** a chunk of memory - it's a variable that **contains** an address that may or may not be valid.

Answer (score 2):

In one module, you **define** an array of `signed char` of size `100` named `buffer`.  This object will use 100 bytes of memory:

```
signed char buffer[100];
```

In another module, you **declare** `buffer` to be something else, a pointer to `signed char`, that is 4 or 8 bytes of memory that may hold the address of an array or that of a single `char`.

```
extern signed char *buffer;
```

The compiler only knows one module at a time, so it cannot check whether this **declaration** is consistent with the actual **definition**.  It compiles code consistently with this declaration, emitting machine code that refers to an external symbol `buffer` that will be resolved at link time.

At link time, the linker does not know about types, it only relies on names.  Therefore it resolves the references to `buffer` from one module with the actual address of the definition from the other module.

At runtime, you get undefined behaviour, because one module uses `buffer` as an array of `signed char`, which it is, and the other loads the value of a pointer from the same address, interpreting the bytes completely differently.

**Declarations** belong in **header** files and should always be included in the **source** file that actually **defines** the object **declared** in the header.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between

```
extern signed char *buffer;
extern signed char buffer[];
```

is the same as you would see when you have

```
signed char *buffer;
signed char buffer[100];
```

in a function.

I see the following differences:

**Difference 1**

When you have:

```
extern signed char *buffer;
```

you can use:

```
buffer = malloc(10);
```

When you have:

```
extern signed char buffer[];
```

you cannot do that.

**Difference 2**

In the first case, it is possible for `buffer` to be NULL. In the second case, it is not.

**Difference 3**

`&buffer` result in different types. For example, you can use:

```
printf("pointer 1: %p\n", &buffer+1);
```

in the first case but you cannot use that in the second case. For `&buffer+1` to work in the second case, you'll have to know the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

This question is more about C linker than about C language.

Although there is a context where `signed char *buffer` and `signed char buffer[]` mean the same thing, `extern` is not one of them. Using `extern` asks the compiler to defer resolving of the external definition to linker. Linker has to be very particular about the difference between pointers and arrays, because the two have different structure in memory, and cannot be treated interchangeably.

Note that although these declarations are different to the linker, they do not change what a programmer could do with such an external array: in both cases you have no access to the size of the declared array (i.e. 100), the syntax to access array elements stays the same, and the pointer arithmetic remains the same.