# How is pointer to array different from array names?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof, pointer-to-array

I was reading more about arrays vs pointers in C and wrote the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int arr[10] = { } ; 
typedef int (*type)[10]  ;
int main()
{
   type val = &arr ; 
   printf("Size is %lu\n", sizeof(val)) ; 
   printf("Size of int is %lu\n", sizeof(int)) ;
}
```

If, I execute this program, then `sizeof(val)` is given to be 8 and `sizeof(int)` is given to be 4.

If `val` is a pointer to the array with 10 elements, shouldn't it's size be 40. Why is the `sizeof(val)` 8 ?

Comment: use `%zu` to print `sizeof`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If val is a pointer to the array...*

Yes, it is, and `sizeof(val)` produces the size for the "**pointer** to the array", not the array itself.

> *...shouldn't it's size be 40.?*

No, `sizeof(val)` calculates the size of the operand, the "pointer" here. In your platform, the size of a pointer seems to be 64 bits, i.e., 8 bytes. So, it gives `8`.

Also, as I mentioned, use `%zu` to print `size_t`, the type produced by `sizeof` operator.

Comment: If that is the case, then what is the difference b/w the types int (*) [10] and types int* ? . How are they different ?

Comment: @ps06756 Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30892273/2173917) answer can help to clear your doubts?

Comment: @ps06756 `int(*)[10]` means a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s while `int*` is just a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: @CoolGuy...(_just to complete your sentence_)..but, _still_, both **are** pointers.

Comment: @CoolGuy Exactly, what I meant was, how is pointing to a whole array different from pointing to its first element ?

Comment: @ps06756 you wrote `sizeof(int)` in your question, that is not a pointer. Did you mean `sizeof(int *)`??

Comment: No, that wasn't a typo. I was just checking the sizeof int on my machine

Comment: @ps06756 "how is pointing to a whole array different from pointing to its first element ?" -- The pointers are indeed of different types but since both are effectively a *pointer*, `sizeof` returns the size of an `int*` pointer and not the array.

Answer (score 3):

First of all this initialization of an array

```
int arr[10] = { } ;
```

is invalid in C. You may not use emplty braces in C (in C++ they are allowed). You have to write

```
int arr[10] = { 0 } ;
```

In C the corresponding initializer is defined the following way

```
initializer:
    { initializer-list }
    { initializer-list , }
```

while in C++

```
braced-init-list:
    { initializer-list ,opt }
    { }
```

As for this statement

```
printf("Size is %lu\n", sizeof(val)) ;
```

then `val` is a pointer because it has type `type` defined like

```
typedef int (*type)[10]  ;
```

Change this statement to

```
printf( "Size is %zu\n",  sizeof( *val ) );
```

if you want to get the size of the object (that is of the array) pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: Good Morning Sir!! Regarding your first statement, can you confirm that empty initializer is invalid in `c99` also? I am sure ISO C forbids it, but not very sure about c99, can you confirm?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Use search and find this answer, there are plenty of them on SO. Then you can update the answer if that bothers you.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh  How do you do, Sir.:)  Please see my updated post.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Empty declaration lists have never been allowed in C. The syntax has always been the same throughout each version of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof returns the size of the pointer itself. In 64bit system it is 8 bytes.
Pointers have no knowledge of the size of buffer they points to.

Comment: If that is the case, then what is the difference b/w the data types int (*) [10] and int* ?

Answer (score 0):

A `pointer` is a distinct data type and always has a fixd size. Think of a pointer as a sign that points to the actual data, and the sign always the same size - regardless if it points to a single character or a larger array.

Comment: If that is the case, then what is the difference b/w the types int (*) [10] and int* ?

Answer (score 0):

`val` is pointer and its size is equivalent to address bus size of system.
so, `sizeof(val)` or `sizeof(anyPointer)` will give you `8` as output.
if you want `40` then try `sizeof(arr)`.

Pointer to an array is simple pointer where you can write `val++` while array name is `constant pointer` you cannot write `arr++`.

you can also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413046/how-to-get-the-length-of-array-in-c-is-sizeof-is-one-of-the-solution)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are in a `64 bit` PC where memory address need `64 bits` or `8 byte` space for representation.

Now the `pointer` actually holds the memory address, whereas it may hold an address of `int` or maybe an address of `int[]`, doesn't matter.

So, when you execute,

```
printf("Size is %lu\n", sizeof(val)) ;
```

it shows `8` as because the pointer holds address which need `64 bits` space.

And

```
printf("Size of int is %lu\n", sizeof(int)) ;
```

this line just print the size of `int` which is `4` bytes.