# Char arrays and scanf function in C

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I expected to get errors in following code, but I did not. I did not use `&` sign. Also I am editing array of `char`s.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     char  name[10] ="yasser";
     printf("%s\n",name);

     // there is no error , 
     // trying to edit array of chars, 
     // also did not use & sign.  
     scanf("%s",name); 

     // did not use strcpy function also.
     printf("%s\n",name);           

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is working correctly, Your expectation is not. What is more to say

Comment: I know I'm wrong,i expect declaration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers

Comment: Just as a side note, `&` sign is called _address-of operator_ `&`.

Comment: Array have fixed size but not fixed content. This means that you can modify the content but not the size, this is the confusion you have?.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that the OP asked if he can modify an Array using`scanf` after he did `char  name[10] ="yasser";`.

Answer (score 12):

> I expected to get errors in following code, but I did not.I did not use & sign.

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

That's totally ok as `name` is already the address of the character array.

Comment: Any array decays to a pointer to it's first element. Therefore you don't need an address.

Comment: Close, but not quite right.  `name` is not the address of the character array.  `name` is the array of size 10.  When `name` is passed to `scanf()`, it is converted to the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: To codify @SenselessCoder's comment, the following will always be true: myArray == &(myArray[0])

Comment: Haha, nice @AaronBurke.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you have several questions:

1. calling `scanf("%s", name)` should have given an error, since `%s` expects a pointer and `name` is an array?  But as others have explained, when you use an array in an expression like this, what you always get (automatically) is a pointer to the array's first element, just as if you had written `scanf("%s", &name[0])`.
2. Having `scanf` write into `name` should have given an error, since `name` was initialized with a string constant?  Well, that's how it was initialized, but `name` really is an array, so you're free to write to it (as long as you don't write more than 10 characters into it, of course).  See more on this below.
3. Characters got copied around, even though you didn't call `strcpy`?  No real surprise, there.  Again, `scanf` just wrote into your array.

Let's take a slightly closer look at what you did write, and what you didn't write.

When you declare and initialize an array of `char`, it's completely different than when you declare and initialize a pointer to `char`.  When you wrote

```
char name[10] = "yasser";
```

what the compiler did for you was sort of as if you had written

```
char name[10];
strcpy(name, "yasser");
```

That is, the compiler arranges to initialize the contents of the array with the characters from the string constant, but what you get is an ordinary, writable array (*not* an unwritable, constant string constant).

If, on the other hand, you had written

```
char *namep = "yasser";
scanf("%s", namep);
```

you would have gotten the problems you expected.  In this case, `namep` is a pointer, not an array.  It's initialized to point to the string constant `"yasser"`, which is not writable.  When `scanf` tried to write to this memory, you probably would have gotten an error.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass arrays to functions in C, they decay to pointers to the first item.

Therefore for:

```
char name[] ="yasser";
```

`scanf("%s", name)` is the same as `scanf("%s", &name[0])` and either of those invocations should send shivers down your spine, because unless you control what's on your `stdin` (which you usually don't), you're reading a potentially very long string into a limited buffer, which is a segmentation fault waiting to happen (or worse, undefined behavior).

Comment: It is the same as `scanf("%s", &name[0])`, but *not* the same as `scanf("%s", &name)`. The latter causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    char *myName = (char *) calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    *(myName)='K'; *(myName+1)='h'; *(myName+2)='a'; *(myName+3)='l'; *(myName+4)='i'; *(myName+5)='d';
    printf("%s\n",myName);
    scanf("%s",myName);
    printf("%s\n",myName);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main()//fonction principale
{

char  name[10] ="yasser";
int longeur=0;
printf("%s\n",name);

scanf("%s",name);
longeur = strlen(name);
for (int i=0;i<longeur;i++) {
    printf("%c",*(name+i));
}
return 0;}
```

Comment: Please add details around how the quoted code works. What mistake the original poster has done and how your suggested solution could help him/her fix the problem. Understanding the 'reason' would help other community members to learn from it as well.