# If arrays are always passed call by reference then how can arrays be passed to functions like printf which are strictly call by value?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Arrays in c are always passed by reference and printf is a call by value function then why do we pass array to printf function for printing a string?

Comment: C  pass always by value, including arrays, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, **arrays are not passed by reference in C**. They *decay* to a pointer, which is passed **by value** to the function.
There is no *pass by reference* in C. It can only be emulated with *pass by value*.

We don't really pass arrays to `printf`: it's the aforementioned pointers we obtain through an implicit conversion (decay). This pointer can just as well be dereferenced to access the content of the array, so passing an array "by value" is not needed at all.

Comment: But we do not write *(name_of_array) as an argument to printf, we simply write the name of array. I mean we write printf("%s",name_of_array) instead of printf("%s",*name_of_array) then how come(given that array is decaying to pointer) is it derefrenced?

Comment: @user6112826 The array is passed as a pointer. The function's parameter for that array is then `T* ptr` where `T` is an arbitrary type. The function can dereference that pointer easily by doing `ptr[N]` where `N` is an arbitrary integral expression like `5` or `i + 2`. Just look at a simply `printf` implementation and you'll understand.

Comment: @user6112826: Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, the compiler will treat `name_of_array` as a pointer to the first element of the array.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers/4608421#4608421) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @JohnBode I know about array decaying, what i was asking is that if contents of arrays are to be copied then we must derefrence it. As name of array is alias to the address of first element of array then should we not derefrence to pass the contents? Because simply passing array would pass the address as it decays to pointer

Comment: @user6112826: "As name of array is alias to the address of first element of array ..." - The prerequisite is already wrong. "decays" (aka "is implicitly converted") does not mean "is identical to". No offence, but please understand stack overflow is not a tutoring site. If the comments and answers here or other related questions still don't help, you should start reading a good C book (there are some for free to be found) from the very beginning. This is very basic stuff about arrays and pointers. Any way, you will not get the picture by asking particular questions.

Comment: @user6112826: The `%s` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to be a pointer value (`char *`); given that address value, it will "walk" down the array and print each character in turn until it sees the 0 terminator.  The function accesses the array's contents via that pointer value.  If you dereference the array name in the argument list, you will wind up passing a single character value, not a sequence of characters.

Comment: "They _decay_ to a pointer,"  Never saw _decay_ defined in a C spec.  Where is _decay_ defined?

Comment: @chux In case you're not being ironic: the term is in widespread use despite the fact it's not described in the standard and denotes the implicit conversion from `T[]` to `T*`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass arrays to printf, instead you pass the values in the array.

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3};
printf("%d",arr);    //Undefined behavior(garbage value)
printf("%d",arr[0]);  //will print 1
```

Also you can pass a pointer as an argument to a function but not a reference in C.

**Edit**
In case of `char*` which is pointer to char ,all characters in the array can be displayed till the NULL character is reached using

```
char* str = "Hello";
printf("%s",str);
```

Comment: `char *` is a special case that should be mentioned.

Comment: It is possible if you create an array of characters and use %s format specifier for printing string.

Comment: @ user6112826 As mentioned by  Fiddling Bits it is a special case.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Your comment is not clear respecting OPs apparent beginner level. I suspect you mean _string literals_. But they actually _don't_ make a difference.

Comment: @user6112826: C does not have a string type. It is all convention: a `char []` with `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: I wasn't specific enough. What I meant was a c-string and the `%s` format specifier are a special case where you pass the address of the array to `printf` and the contents are printed, not the address.

Comment: @Fiddling Bits you mean there is an implicit dereferencing of the array in this case?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Ok, but that does not make the "string" different, but just how the `%s` type specifier is interpreted by `printf`. (Sorry for nit-picking, but OP is already confused enough:-)

Comment: The correct format specifier for printing memory addresses is `%p`, not `%d`. You also need to cast its argument to `void*`.

Comment: @Cool Guy Is the output of printf("%d",arr) just garbage value ?

Comment: @XYZProgrammer Could be anything due to Undefined Behavior as per the C standards. Use `printf("%p", (void*)arr);` instead.