# Pointers of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

In the case down below.
Does changing the string 'out' change the string 'str' respectively? In other words, do they have the same pointer?

Thank you in advance.

```
int main() {
  char str[]={'g','o','o','d','/0'};
  char special[]={'o','/0'};
  char* out=str;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s

Comment: So what happened when you tried it? You should also be aware that strings are terminated with `\0`.

Comment: note that `'/0'` should probably be `\0`

Comment: Honestly, how about just trying it?

Comment: "*Does changing the string 'out'  [...]*" `out` isn't a string, but a pointer, a pointer to a `char`.

Answer (score 5):

It depends.  If you write:

```
out = "hello!";
```

you do not change the string `str`, but simply make `out` point to another memory location.

But if you write into `out` like in this:

```
sprintf(out, "abcd");
```

then you do change `str`. But beware of overflow!

Answer (score 5):

For starters I think you mean the terminating zero `'\0'` instead of the multibyte character literal '/0'.

To escape such an error it is better to initialize character arrays with string literals (if you are going to store a string in an array). For example

```
char str[] = { "good" };
```

or just like

```
char str[] = "good";
```

As for the question then after this assignment

```
char* out=str;
```

the pointer `out` points to the first character of the array `str`.  Thus using this pointer and the pointer arithmetic you can change the array. For example

```
char str[] = "good";
char *out = str;

out[0] = 'G';
*( out + 3 ) = 'D';

puts( str );
```

Moreover an array passed as an argument to a function is implicitly converted to pointer to its first character. So you can use interchangeably either an array itself as an argument or a pointer that initialized by the array designator. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//...

char str[] = "good";
char *out = str;

size_t n1 = strlen( str );
size_t n2 = strlen( out ); 

printf( "n1 == n2 is %s\n", n1 == n2 ? "true" : "false" );
```

The output of this code snippet is `true`.

However there is one important difference. The size of the array is the number of bytes allocated to all its elements while the size of the pointer usually either equal to 4 or 8 based on used system and does not depend on the number of elements in the array. That is

```
sizeof( str ) is equal to 5
sizeof( out ) is equal to 4 or 8
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a typo in your code, you have written `'/0'` but it's not a null character but `'\0'` is.
As far as `out` & `str` are concerned, `str[]` is a char array, whereas `out` is a pointer to it. If you make `out` point to some other `char array` there'll be no effect on `str`. But you can use `out` pointer to change the values inside the `str[]`, like this,

```
int main( void )
{
  char str[]={'g','o','o','d','\0'}; // There was a typo, you wrote '/0', I guess you meant '\0'
  //char special[]={'o','\0'};
  char* out=str;
  for(int i=0; out[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
     out[i] = 'a';
     // This will write 'a' to the str[] 
  }
  printf("out: %s\n", out);
  printf("str: %s", str);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. `out` is a different variable that holds the same address `str` is at, i.e. it points to the same location. Note that changing `*str` will change `*out`.

In C, assignment takes the value of the right end and stores it in the left end, it does not makes the right "become" left

Comment: `str` doesn't hold an address. It's an array.

Comment: @StoryTeller What's the difference in C?

Comment: @klutt - [You won't find a better explanation than this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers)

Comment: @StoryTeller I used that since str == &str. I tried to correct my answer

Comment: @CIsForCookies - `str == &str` should raise several compiler warnings about comparing incompatible pointer types. The fact `str` decays to the address of its first byte when used in an expression, doesn't make it a pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller Indeed, but the values are the same, so what I was thinking is that I can look at 'str' as an array and as a pointer to the first element and thus I can say str holds an address. I'm just rationalizing my mistake... clearly it was wrong :)

Comment: @ClsForCookies a *pointer* is a stored object itself, so you have some location containing the value of the pointer. As a consequence, you can for example **assign a different value** to a pointer. The stored object of the array is just the sequence of its elements. Evaluating the identifier of the array results in a pointer to its first element, but that doesn't make the array a pointer. You can't assign to it, for example.