# Which § in C99 says that an array is passed to a function without copy in C?

Tags: c, arguments, c99

I recently noticed that

```
void foo(int array[10]);
```

Does not load the stack with the content of array when `foo` is called, so the declaration is equivalent to:

```
void foo(int *array):
```

I would like to find the section in the C99 standard that assert this behavior, but I don't find anything or I don't know what I should search for. So far I tried `by reference`, `by value`, `function call`, `passing arguments`, ...

Comment: It's equivalent to `void foo(int *array)`, not to `void foo(int (*array)[10]);`.

Comment: @interjay You are probably right because I get no warning with `int func(int B[10]) {return B[11];}`. This looks sad...

Comment: @interjay Thanks, I fixed the question with your correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C11 6.7.6.3 §7.  (C99 6.7.5.3 §7)

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
>   ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are
>   those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation.

The term is formally named "array adjustment". Informally outside the C standard, it is usually referred to as "array decay".

Comment: @nowox I've probably just been reading the standard far too much.

Comment: "Array adjustment" is a good term for it, although I've never encountered anyone referring to it as "array decay" (although "array decay" is a common way of referring to the automatic conversion of an lvalue of array type to a (non-lvalue) pointer).

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah, the term array decay is sloppily used both to describe when an array type is used in an expression, and when it is part of a parameter list. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868367/whats-a-modern-term-for-array-pointer-equivalence).