# Do pointers support "array style indexing"?

Tags: c, arrays, pointer-arithmetic, subscript-operator, array-indexing

*(Self-answered Q&A - this matter keeps popping up)*

I assume that the reader is aware of how pointer arithmetic works.

```
int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
int* ptr = arr;
...
*(ptr + i) = value;
```

Teachers/C books keep telling me I shouldn't use `*(ptr + i)` like in the above example, because "pointers support array style indexing" and I should be using `ptr[i] = value;` instead. No argument there - much easier to read.

But looking through the C standard, I find nothing called "array style indexing". In fact, the operator `[]` is not expecting either operand to be an array, but instead a pointer or an integer!

> **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to complete object *type*’’, the other expression shall have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘*type*’’.

Why does the *array* subscripting operator not expect an array? Is the standard wrong? Is my teacher/C book confused?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should indeed be using `ptr[i]` over `*(ptr + i)` for readability reasons. But apart from that, the `[]` operator is, strictly speaking, actually never used with an array operand.

Arrays, when used in an expression, always "decay" into a pointer to the first element (with some exceptions). C17 6.3.2.1/3, emphasis mine:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue.

Meaning that whenever you type `arr[i]`, the operand `arr` gets replaced by a pointer to the first element inside that array. This is informally referred to as "array decaying". More info here: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

So whenever you use the `[]` operator, you use it on a pointer. Always.

The C standard says that this operator is guaranteed to be equivalent to the pointer arithmetic (C17 6.5.2.1/2):

> The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.

So whenever we type `arr[i]`, it actually gets silently replaced by `*(arr+i)`. Where `arr` is still a pointer to the first element.

And this is why the description you quoted tells you that *either* operand could be a pointer and the other an integer. Because obviously it doesn't matter if we type  `*(arr+i)` or `*(i+arr)` - that's equivalent code.

Which in turn allows us to write obfuscated "joke" code like `i[arr]`, which is actually valid C and fully equivalent to `arr[i]`. But don't write such code in real applications.

Comment: Assembly language programmers who were required to write `offset(register)` for decades may be forgiven for writing `i[array]`.

Comment: We can write i[arr] because the standard uses the term "one of the expressions... " in 6.5.2.1 instead of "The first expression... "