# Expression of array of function pointer in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm C beginner and I learned a pointer can be expressed in an array and vice versa.
Like `*p == p[0]`, `p[1][2] == *(*(p+1)+2)`
Does these lead to `*p[i](arg1, arg2) == p[0][i](arg1, arg2)`?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a 2d-array of function pointers. I STRONGLY advice you to reconsider...

Comment: If I ever ended up having to deal with a 2d-array of function pointers, I would do something like this: `int (*f)(int, int) = p[0][i]; int ret = f(arg1, arg2);`

Comment: @ klutt nd-pointer and nd-array which have each different memory structure but each expression can be compatible. I wonder is this same for a function pointer? You sad 2d-array of function pointers, when I heard this, I can image only `*p[i][j](arg1, arg2)`

Comment: @opol pointers and arrays are not compatible (whatever you understand by compatible) - it may look that they are but they are not.

Comment: It seems like you need to read a lot to understand the very basics. `p[i]` is syntactic sugar for `*(p+i)`. Nothin more. Nothing less. Pointers and arrays are two separate things.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers

Comment: @P__J__ I can't sure my writing is sufficient to show my query. What I wonder is not during coding something that each code is brief example for my question.

Comment: @opol I voted to close as you need to put some more effort into it to make it clear.

Comment: @klutt Pedantically, `p[i]` is rather syntactic sugar for `*((p)+(i))` which is part of the OP's problem.

Comment: @klutt Also, I recall finding a valid use-case for a 2D array of function pointers. I once used that in an embedded system finite state machine, where each state had a state machine of its own. Alas, I was the only one who understood what the code did, so my colleagues urged me to refactor it. I ended up with just an array of function pointers and let each state handle it's own state machine internally. So it was more de-centralized, better OO design... but still, I think this was a valid use-case for the original 2D array.

Comment: @Lundin Sure, it exists use cases. But they are very rare. I would say that if you use them often enough to motivate learning the strange syntax instead of using an intermediate pointer, then you're doing something wrong. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function pointers behave just like ordinary object pointers. An array used in an expression will decay into a pointer (*not* vice versa!), which allows us to use the `[]` operator, which in turn requires the left operand to be a pointer.

This is explained here: [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing)

The problem with your specific code is that postfix operators such as `[]` take precedence over unary operators such as `*`. Meaning that `(*p)[i](arg1, arg2)` is equivalent to `p[0][i](arg1, arg2)`. The latter is clearly preferred since it is far more readable.

Answer (score 3):

> Does these lead to *p[i](arg1, arg2) == p[0][i](arg1, arg2)?

Not really, `*p[i](arg1, arg2)` is parsed as `*(p[i](arg1, arg2))` - it applies the `*` dereference operator on the result of function call.

`p[0][i](arg1, arg2)` is equal to `(*p)[i](arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: `p[0][i](arg1, arg2)` is equal to `(*p)[i](arg1, arg2)`. Then Is `(*p)[i](arg1, arg2)` equal to `*((*p)+i)(arg1, arg2)`?

Comment: `(*((*p)+i))(arg1, arg2)`. The `*` operator has higher precedence then `(` function call operator. The `*((*p)+i)(arg1, arg2)` is the same as `*( ((*p)+i)(arg1, arg2) )`

Answer (score 2):

Learning of programming involves a lots experimenting. The tiny program below shows that your assumption `*p[2] == p[0][2]` is wrong.

```
#define f(x)  void f ## x(void) {printf("Func = %d\n", x);}

f(10);f(11);f(12);
f(20);f(21);f(22);
f(30);f(31);f(32);


int main()
{
    void (*p[3][3])(void) = {{f10, f11, f12}, {f20, f21, f22}, {f30, f31, f32}};

    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            printf("%p\t", (void *)p[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\np[0][2] = %p\n", (void *)p[0][2]);
    printf("*p[2] = %p\n", (void *)*p[2]); 
}
```

and the result:

```
0x4005b2    0x4005cd    0x4005e8    
0x400603    0x40061e    0x400639    
0x400654    0x40066f    0x40068a    

p[0][2] = 0x4005e8
*p[2] = 0x400654
```

Such a experiments will give you more understanding of this topic than 1000 online questions. Put some effort in your learning. If you do not understand something - write something like this to see how it works.