# Is dereferencing a pointer equal to getting it's first index?

Tags: c

Assume this:

```
int a = 5;
int *p = &a;

int c = *p;
int d = p[0];
```

So is `*p` equivalent to `p[0]` in the world of the pointers and arrays?

Comment: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a

Comment: If by "equivalent," you mean "they return the same thing," yes, they do.  Obviously your choice of which to use will depend on what your stated intent is in your code.

Comment: This might be more helpful: [Do pointers support “array style indexing”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing).