# How are *(a + 2) and a[1] related?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

We have the variable `a`, that is the type `char*`, that stores `char`s in an array. How are `*(a + 2)` and `a[1]` related?

`a[1]` points to the second element in the array and `*(a + 2)` points to the second element following the element pointed at to by `a`. So would the values of these two be the same?

Comment: Wouldn't `a + 2` rather point to the 3rd element?

Comment: Related: [Do pointers support “array style indexing”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are *not* the same.

The syntax `E1[E2]` is exactly equivalent to `*((E1) + (E2))`.  So `*(a + 2)` is the same as `a[2]`.  It should now be clear that this is not the same as `a[1]`.

Comment: Pedantically, it's `*((E1) + (E2))`. Otherwise it would break in case E2 was something like `1<<1` with lower precedence than +.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have `char a[] = "bar";` and t goes to address 0xdeadbeec

```
     | address                  | contents
-----+--------------------------+------------------
high | 0xdeadbeef &a[3]; a+3    | '\0' *(a+3); a[3]
     | 0xdeadbeee &a[2]; a+2    | 'r'  *(a+2); a[2]
     | 0xdeadbeed &a[1]; a+1    | 'a'  *(a+1); a[1]
low  | 0xdeadbeec a; &a[0]; a+0 | 'b'  *(a); a[0]
```

Note that both though `a` and `&a[0]` *refer* to the same memory address, they have different types. The type of `a` is `char[4]`, the type of `&a[0]` is `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

`a[i]` (where `a` is a pointer and `i` is an integer type) is exactly `*(a + i)`. So in your example case with `char *a;`, the expression `a[1]` is the `char` at address `a + 1`.
ASCII art schema:

```
   a[0] a[1] a[2] a[3] a[4]
  +----+----+----+----+----+...
a |    |    |    |    |    |...
  +----+----+----+----+----+...
   a+0  a+1  a+2  a+3  a+4
```

So, the answer to your question is *no*. `a[2]` is just one char after `a[1]`.