# Is the line (*x=y) equal to the line (x[0]=y) in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am confused about C syntax. If I allocate memory:

```
int* x = (int*)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
```

Are these two code snippets of an int pointer equal?

```
*x = 0;
```

And

```
x[0] = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, it is equal.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(x)` is not necessarily the correct size to allocate space for an `int` because `x` is a pointer and, in some implementations sizeof a pointer is different to sizeof an int. Use `int *x = malloc(sizeof *x);` (with no redundant cast, remember to `#include <stdlib.h>`)

Comment: More generally `*(x+y)` is strictly the same as `x[y]`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: or `y[x]`... *3["foobar"] == "foobar"[3] == \*(3 + "foobar") == 'b'*

Comment: And more interestingly it's the same as `0[x] = y;`.

Comment: @anastaciu: Can you explain why it is more interesting other than _it's good to know_ ? Are there some usecases for it?

Comment: @pqans, when I first realized this could be done I though it was interesting at the time, explanations are plentiful in the platform, a simple search renders you several results, but realizing that `*(0 + x)` is the same as  `0[x]` kind of explains itself.

Comment: Wrong size: `int* x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(x));` --> `int* x = malloc(sizeof *x);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of the `[]` operator is: given `ex1[ex2]`, it is guaranteed to be equivalent to

```
*((ex1) + (ex2))
```

Where `ex1` and `ex2` are expressions.

In your case `x[0]` == `*(x + 0)` == `*(x)` == `*x`.

See [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing) for details.