# C Compilers -- Indirection with Multidim Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, compiler-construction, code-generation

By definition, in every standard of C, x[y] is equivalent to (and often compiled as) *((x)+(y)). Additionally, a name of an array is converted to an address operator to it -- so if x is an array, it would be *((&(x))+(y))

So, for a multidimension array, x as a 2 dimension array, x[y][z] would be equivalent to *(*((&(x))+(y))+(z))

In the small scale toy C compiler I'm working on, this fails to generate proper code, because it tries to indirectly access a pointed to address at every * instruction -- this works for single dimension arrays, but for multi dimension it results in something like (in vaguely assembly pseudocode)

```
load &x; add y; deref; add z; deref
```

Where deref is an instruction to load the value at the address of the previous calculation -- as this is how the indirection operator seems to work??

However, this will generate bad code, since we should be dealing all with a single address, only dereferencing at the very end. I'm assuming there's something in the spec I'm missing?

Comment: *"name of an array is converted to an address operator to it"* No. You could say that `x` is converted to `&x[0]`, which has different type compared to `&x`.

Comment: Arrays aren't converted to pointers when used as L-values, only R-values.

Comment: What `deref` does depends on the type, and you have to detect that. Generally, yes, `deref() { if simple pointer; then deref; if array; then only remove one dimension from type and don't change the value, if pointer to function, then do nothing }`

Comment: Aaand there's also the case where `&*` is a no-op, so you have to check if the next operation is `&` and then do nothing, for example.

Answer (score 2):

> name of an array is converted to an address operator to it

No. You could say that `x` is converted to `&x[0]`, which has different type compared to `&x`.

Assuming you have `T a[M][N];`, doing `a[x][y]` does following:

- `a` is converted to a temporary pointer of type `T (*)[N]`, pointing to the first array element.
- This pointer is incremented by `x * sizeof(T[N])`, i.e. by `x * N * sizeof(T)`.
- The pointer is dereferenced, giving you a value of type `T[N]`.
- The result is converted to a temporary pointer of type `T *`.
- The pointer is incremented by `y * sizeof(T)`.
- Finally, the pointer is dereferenced to produce a value of type `T`.

Note that an array itself (multidimensional or not) doesn't store any pointers to itself. When converted to a pointer, the resulting pointer is calculated on the fly.

Comment: This is giving the same result? I think my issue might be more in what the indirection operator is supposed to output?? Should it have more complex logic to detect this? Because when T(*)[N] is dereferenced, it sees T(*[N]) as a pointer and tries to get the value at that address?

Comment: @PopeyeOtaku You were asking "why 2 dereferences rather than 1", and the answer is "because there are 2 temporary pointers". *"Should it have more complex logic"* No, there is no complex logic here, except the fact that arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first element when passed to `[]`.

Comment: *"when T(*)[N] is dereferenced, it sees T(*[N]) as a pointer and tries to get the value at that address"* The result of the dereference has type `T[N]`. When it's converted to a pointer (before the second addition), the resulting pointer is computed on the fly, rather than being taken from some memory location..

Answer (score 0):

> So, for a multidimension array, x as a 2 dimension array, x[y][z] would be equivalent to (((&(x))+(y))+(z))

No, a 2D array is an array of arrays. So `*((x)+(y))` gives you that array, `x` decays into a pointer to the first element, which is then de-referenced to give you array number `y`.

This array too "decays" into a pointer of the first element, so you get:

```
( (*((x)+(y))) + (z) )
```

When part of an expression, arrays always decay into a pointer to it's first element. Except for a few exceptions, namely the `&` address of and `sizeof` operators. Why typing out the `&` as done in your pseudo code is just confusing.

A practical example would be:

```
int arr[x][y];
for(size_t i=0; i<x; i++)
  for(size_t j=0; j<y; j++)
    arr[i][j] = ...
```

- In the expression `arr[i][j]`, the `[]` is just "syntactic sugar" for pointer arithmetic (see [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing)).
- So we get `*((arr)+(i))`, where `arr` is decayed into a pointer to the type of the first element, `int(*)[y]`.
- Pointer arithmetic on that array pointer type yields array number `i` of type `int [y]`.
- Again, there is array decay on this one, because it too is an array part of an expression. We get a pointer to the first element, type `int*`.
- Pointer arithmetic of the `int*` + `j` gives the address of the integer, which is then finally de-referenced to give the actual `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> So, for a multidimension array, x as a 2 dimension array, x[y][z]
> would be equivalent to (((&(x))+(y))+(z))

You are mistaken. The expression x[y][z] is evaluated like:

```
*( *( x + y ) + z )
```

Here is a demonstration program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 3, N = 3 };
    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *( *( a + i ) + j ) );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Array designators used in expressions (with rare exceptions) are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

So if you have an array declared like:

```
int a[M][N];
```

then the array designator `a` is converted to a pointer to its first element ("row"). The type of the array element is int[N]. So a pointer to such object has the type `int ( * )[N]`.

If you want that a pointer point to the `i-th` element of the array you need to write the expression `a + i`.  Dereferencing the expression you will get the i-th row (one-dimensional array) that in turn used in expressions is converted to a pointer to its first element.

So the expression `a + i` has the type `int ( * )[N]`.

The expression `*( a + i )` has the type `int[N]` that at once is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `int *` to its firs element in the enclosing expression.

The expression `*( a + i ) + j`  points to the `j-th` element of the "row" of the two-dimensional array. Dereferencing the expression `*( *( a + i ) + j )` you will get the `j-th` element of the `i-th` row of the array.