# which one is the correct type of an array variable? (for using with pointers in C)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

If i want to initialize a pointer to an int to an array, i need to use this notation:

```
int data[] = {34,35,36};
int *ptr = &data[0];
```

because the type of the variable `data` is `int[]`, that's the reason why the next declaration gives warnings:

```
int *ptr = &data;
```

In the case above I'm assigning an "array type" to an int pointer, it's a mistake and is ok.
So, why is it possible to use the next code to iterate in the array:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    *(data+i);
```

What the line above should do is to add the size of the full array in every iteration and the correct code should be as shown below:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    *(&data[0] + i);
```

but if we test them, both are equals and correct to iterate in the array.

So, the type of the variable data (alone, without []) should be thought as int[] or int?
how can i know when a variable will have one type or another to do correct pointer aritmethic.

Comment: The type of `&data` is `int (*)[3]`, which is incompatible with `int *`.

Comment: You should be able to init the pointer like this... int *ptr = data;

Comment: Also note that arrays naturally *decay* to pointers to their first element. So you can use `data` as it were a pointer (the compiler will treat it as `&data[0]`). Also note that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`.

Comment: @Danstern At first you said `If i want to initialize an int pointer to an array` that seems odd and confusing, it is a pointer to an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases whenever an array name is used in an expression, it decays into a pointer to it's first element. Therefore `int *ptr = &data[0];` is 100% equivalent to `int *ptr = data;`.

As for accessing individual items of an array, or of an array pointed at through a pointer to the first element, `arr[i]` is 100% equivalent to `*(arr + i)`, the latter is just needlessly hard to read. See [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing)

However, one exception to the mentioned array decay rule is when an array name is used as operand to the `&` operator. In that case it does not decay - instead we get a pointer to "the array as whole". In your case `int *ptr = &data;` is an invalid pointer conversion because `&data` is of type `int(*)[3]`, a pointer to array.

Please note however that in the expression `&data[i]`, operator precedence says that `[]` "binds tighter" to the `data` operand than `&`. So it is equivalent to `&(data[i])`. The previously mentioned exception to array decay does not apply, since the `&` is never applied to the array name, but to an item in the array. Array decay into a pointer to the first element has already happened when we reach `&`, since it happened at the point where `[]` was encountered.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array  object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

And (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Thus in this expression

```
*(data+i)
```

the array `data` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. And the expression is equivalent to `data[i]` or `i[data]`.

So the expression

```
 *(&data[0] + i);
```

can be rewritten like

```
 *(&*( data + 0 ) + i);
```

that is the same as

```
 *( data + 0 + i);
```

and in turn as

```
 *( data + i);
```

Also in the declaration of a pointer

```
int *ptr = &data[0];
```

you could just write

```
int *ptr = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After reading your comments i discovered the concept "**array decay**".
The name of an array naturally **decays** into a pointer to the type of the array; for example, if i declare `int data[5]`, the type of `data` will be `int*` most of the times, but there are some exceptions to this **decay**. There are more information abut it here: [exceptions to array decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exceptions-to-array-decaying-into-a-pointer)

My confussion got from that: sometimes when i used an array, it decayed and other times it didn't.

Comment: I think your confusion is just how the operator precedence of `&data[i]` works, see the answer I just posted.