# How to change arrangement of element using pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my code, how can I change line 9 to line 11 in pointer form?

```c
void ShiftRightCircular (ElemType *A, int n, int k) {
    /************** begin *****************/
    ElemType e;
    int p, i = 0;
    while (i < n - k) {
        p = i / k + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < k ; j++) {
            e = A[j];                // line 9
            A[j] = A[ (p * k + j) % n]; // line 10
            A[ (p * k + j) % n] = e; // line 11
            i++;
        }
    }
    /************** end *****************/
}
```

Comment: Here is my code, how can I change line 9 to line 11 in pointer form?

void ShiftRightCircular(ElemType *A,int n,int k)
{
/************** begin *****************/
ElemType e;
int p,i=0;
while(i<n-k){
p=i/k+1;
for(int j=0; j<k ;j++){
e=A[j];
A[j]=A[(p*k+j)%n];
A[(p*k+j)%n]=e;
i++;
}
}
/**************  end  *****************/
}

Comment: Please post code as text, not as pictures of text.

Comment: `array[index]` is 100% equivalent to `*(array + index)`

Comment: You probably do not want `e` to be a pointer. Suggestion: avoid hiding pointerness within a `typedef`.

Comment: What is `ElemType`? Please show a [mcve]. Also please tell us why you want to change lines 9 to line 11 to pointer form. Also please make clear if its `ElemType *A` like in the picture of your code or `ElemType A` like in code you posted in the comment. BTW: never post multiline code in comments, it's unreadable as you can see

Comment: Related: [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

[`array[index]` is 100% equivalent to `*(array + index)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010282/how-to-change-arrangement-of-element-using-pointer-in-c#comment127242236_72010282)

Candidate replacement:

```
int d = (p * k + j) % n;  // Used to simplify the following:

e = *(A + j);        // e = A[j];
*(A + j) = *(A + d); // A[j] = A[ (p * k + j) % n];
*(A + d) = e;        // A[ (p * k + j) % n] = e;
```

---

Note: `(p * k + j) % n` better as `(1LL * p * k + j) % n` to avoid overflow.