# Pointer arithmetic in C when used as a target array for strcat()

Tags: arrays, c, string, strcat

When studying string manipulation in C, I've come across an effect that's not quite what I would have expected with `strcat()`. Take the following little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[20] = "abcde";
    strcat(string + 1, "fghij");
    printf("%s", string);

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect this program to print out `bcdefghij`. My thinking was that in C, strings are arrays of characters, and the name of an array is a pointer to its first element, i.e., the element with index zero. So the variable `string` is a pointer to `a`. But if I calculate `string + 1` and use that as the destination array for concatenation with `strcat()`, I get a pointer to a memory address that's one array element (`1 * sizeof(char)`, in this case) away, and hence a pointer to the `b`. So my thinking was that the target destination is the array starting with `b` (and ending with the invisible null character), and to that the `fghij` is concatenated, giving me `bcdefghij`.

But that's not what I get - the output of the program is `abcdefghij`. It's the exact same output as I would get with `strcat(string, "fghij");` - the addition of the 1 to `string` is ignored. I also get the same output with an addition of another number, e.g.  `strcat(string + 4, "fghij");`, for that matter.

Can somebody explain to me why this is the case? My best guess is that it has to do with the binding precedence of the `+` operator, but I'm not sure about this.

Edit: I increased the size of the original array with `char string[20]` so that it will, in any case, be big enough to hold the concatenated string. Output is still the same, which I think means the array overflow is not key to my question.

Comment: The program is invalid as it has Undefined Behaviour. `string` only has space for the exact string it is initialised with. You are writing past the end of the array.

Comment: `string + 1` evaluates to a pointer to `string[1]`, i.e. the letter `b`.  But the value of `string` itself, as a pointer expression, does not change.  So evaluating `string` in the next line to pass to `printf` still returns a pointer to the original first character.

Comment: Just like writing `int x = 7; print(x+3); print(x);` would print 10 and then 7.  The `+` operator does not modify either of its operands.  Nothing at all to do with precedence.

Comment: To avoid the overrun bug (which I think is beside the point of your actual question), change `char string[] = "abcde";` to something like `char string[11] = "abcde";`.  That will help you get more relevant answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get an output of `abcdefghij`, because your call to `strcat` hasn't changed the address of `string` (and nor *can* you change that – it's fixed for the duration of the block in which it is declared, just like the address of any other variable). What you are passing to `strcat` is the address of the *second* element of the `string` array: but that is still interpreted as the address of a `nul`-terminated string, to which the call appends the second (source) argument. Appending that second argument's content to `string`, `string + 1` or `string + n` will produce the same result in the `string` array, so long as there is a `nul`-terminator at or after the `n` index.

To print the value of the string that you *actually* pass to the `strcat` call (i.e., starting from the `'b'` character), you can save the [return value of the call](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat) and print that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[20] = "abcde";
    char* result = strcat(string + 1, "fghij"); // strcat will return the "string + 1" pointer
    printf("%s", result); // bcdefghij

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That covers squarely what I've been wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

```
    char string[] = "abcde";
    strcat(string + 1, "fghij");
```

Append five characters to a full string array. Booom. Undefined behavior.

Adding something to a string array is a performance optimization that tells the runtime that the string is known to be at least that many characters long.

You seem to believe that a string is a thing of its own and not an array, and `strcat` is doing something to its first argument. That's not how that works. Strings are arrays*; and strcat is modifying the array contents.

<sup>*Somebody's going to come by and claim that heap allocated strings are not arrays. OP is not dealing with heap yet.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are non-modibfiable lvalues. For example you may not write

```
char string[20] = "abcde";
char string2[] = ""fghij"";

string = string2;
```

Used in expressions arrays with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

If you will write for example `string + 1` then the address of the array will not be changed.

In this call

```
strcat(string + 1, "fghij");
```

elements of the array string are being overwritten starting from the second element of the array.

In this statement

```
printf("%s", string);
```

there is outputted the whole array starting from its first character (again the array designator used as an argument is converted to a pointer to its first element).

You could write for example

```
printf("%s", string + 1);
```

In this case the array is outputted starting from its second element.

Answer (score 0):

These are just two pointers to different parts of the same memory inside the same array. There is nothing in your code which creates a second array. "the name of an array is a pointer to its first element" well, not really, it *decays* into a pointer to its first element whenever used in an expression. So in case of `string + 1`, this decay first happens to the `string` operand and then you get pointer arithmetic afterwards. You can actually never do pointer arithmetic on array types, only on decayed pointers. Details here: [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55747822/584518)

As for `strcat`, it basically does two things: call `strlen` on the original string to find where it ends, then call `strcpy` to append the new string at the position where the null terminator was stored. It's the very same thing as typing `strcpy(&src[strlen(src)], dst);`

Therefore it won't matter if you pass `string + 1` or `string`, because in either case `strcat` will look for the null terminator and nothing else.