# Question regarding output of printf in handling pointer to array

Tags: c, pointers

I was comparing various `printf` to better understand the difference between `int *` and `int (*)[]` and how i can visualize various addresses and values.

In the following program i wrote one thing bothers me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
    int a[3] = {1,2,3};
    int *p = a;                             
    
    printf("address of a:  %p\n", &a);
    printf("\naddress of a[0]:  %p\n", &a[0]);
    printf("\nvalue of p:  %p\n", p);
    printf("\nvalue of *p:  %d\n", *p);
    printf("\nvalue of a[1]:  %d\n", *(p + 1));
    
    puts("\n\n-------------------\n\n");
    
    int b[3] = {1,2,3};
    int (*q)[3] = &b;
    
    printf("address of b:  %p\n", &b);
    printf("\naddress of b[0]:  %p\n", &b[0]);
    printf("\nvalue of q:  %p\n", q);
    printf("\nvalue of *q:  %p\n", *q);
}
```

In the first part `p`, as a pointer, holds as value the address of `a[0]`, so `*p` holds as value `1` ( printed with %d).

In the second part, though, `q` seems to hold the same value of `*q` (in this case i use %p), therefore i need to use `**q` to print `b[0]`.

How come?

Comment: An array and its first element have the same address, but the type of corresponding pointers is different.

Comment: "so *p holds as value 1"... No, `*p` POINTS at the value (that happens to be 1)... `p` is a variable whose datatype is `pointer to int` meaning `p` can hold a memory address (point to), in this case, an `int`... I hope this helps...

Comment: As a bonus, you could also observe the value of `q + 1` (not `*(q + 1)`, beware), compared to `p + 1`. Please note that you should cast to `void *`, when using `%p`.

Comment: `int *p = a;` is exactly the same as (shorthand for) `int *p = &a[ 0 ];` Perhaps seeing this will make it more obvious that `p` is assigned the address of the first element of `a[ ]`...

Comment: @Lundin yes, you are right. Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you dereference a plain pointer like `int*` you get an item of type `int`.
- When you dereference an array pointer like `int (*q)[3]` you get an array of type `int [3]`.

Now, whenever you use an array in an expression (in most cases) it decays into a pointer to its first element. So `*q` gives you an array `int [3]` which then immediately decays into a pointer to the first element, type `int*`. And that's the pointer you'll be printing. We can prove that this is the case by executing this snippet:

```
_Generic(*q, 
         int*:      puts("we ended up with an int*"), 
         int(*)[3]: puts("this wont get printed") );
```

In order to print the value pointed at by that pointer, you therefore need another level of dereferencing: either `(*q)[0]` or `**q`.

Comment: I see, and that's also the same reason i need to write ```*(*q + 1)``` for ```b[1]``` instead of  ```*(q + 1)```, is that correct?

Comment: @Talete Kind of, yes. In case of `*q + 1` pointer arithmetic is carried out on type `int*` but in case of `q + 1` it is carried out on type `int (*)[3]` And in the latter case + 1 means + the size of a whole `int [3]` array.

Comment: "`*q` gives you an array `int [3]` which then immediately decays into a pointer to the first element," is a bit off on the immediacy. `*q` is the array.   `sizeof *q` is the size of the array.   `_Generic(*q, ...` does print  "we ended up with an int*" though because `*q` is used in an _expression_?  Interesting `_Generic` does that step.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It has to decay because it isn't possible to pointer arithmetic on arrays, only on pointers. Similarly, the array subscripting operator `[]` can actually not be used on arrays. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing.

Comment: @Lundin when you say "It has to decay because ...", are you applying that to `_Generic(*q,...` which does not has pointer arithmetic on arrays?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica _Generic is an expression and it's neither sizeof nor & so why wouldn't the array decay?

Comment: Because it was not clear to me  that `_Generic` is an expression.  Given your assertion, that it is, then it well addresses the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73385442/question-regarding-output-of-printf-in-handling-pointer-to-array/73385692?noredirect=1#comment129610506_73385692).

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `q` points to an array of 3 integers. You can visualise it like this:

```
                 
  q -----> |b = {1,2,3}|
                
 
// q points to the whole array.
// note how it doesn't point to a specific element.
```

Your print statements broken down:

- `&b` - this is the base address of `b`.

```
|b = {1,2,3}| // address of whole array
```

- `&b[0]` - this is the address of the `0th` element of `b`.

```
   b = {1,2,3}
        ^
// address of b[0]
```

- `q` - this points to the base address of `b` and holds the same value as `&b`.

```
q -----> |b = {1,2,3}| // address of whole array
```

- `*q` - this will yield the address of the first element of `b`, in your case this is the address of `b[0]`.

```
 b = {1,2,3}
*q ---^
```

In regards to your question:

With `q` you must dereference twice (`**q`) because:

- `q` points to the base address of `b`
- if we dereference once (`*q`) it will yield the address of `b[0]`.
- if we dereference once more (`**q`) we will get the value in `b[0]`.

Here is a visualization that may help you understand how it works.

```
- q -----> |b = {1,2,3}|  // points to base address of b
- *q ------------^ // points to address of b[0]
- **q -----------^ // value of b[0]
```

Comment: "*q - this will yield the address of the first element of b" --> `*q` is the array.  Converting to the address of the first element of b depends on the surrounding code, like another `*` as in `**q`.

Comment: OP has ```printf("\nvalue of *q: %p\n", *q);``` in the code so in this case it will yield a implicitly decayed pointer to the first element of ```b``` which is ```b[0]```.