# what does *(x + 1) mean in C (where x is an array)

Tags: arrays, c, pointer-arithmetic

I came across this in an assignment. Obviously * denotes a pointer but what does *(x+1) mean. I assumed it adds one to the address (x[0]) of x but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: For any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(a + i)`.

Comment: *"it adds one to the address (x[0])"*. It adds the **size of one element**.

Comment: @SouravGhosh no, you don't. One can very well start coding only knowing about `x[1]`.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate: [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing)

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as to write `x[1]`. That is it yields the second element of the array.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Pay attention to that due to commutativity the expression `*( x + 1 )` also may be written like `1[x]`.

The subscript operator is defined like

```
postfix-expression [ expression ]
```

So for example this expression

```
p++[i]
```

is equivalent to

```
*( p++ + i )
```

while this expression

```
++p[i]
```

is equivalent to

```
++*( p + i )
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x = 10;
    int *p = &x;

    printf( "x = %d, p = %p\n", x, ( void * )p );

    printf( "p++[0] = %d, ", p++[0] );
    printf( "p = %p\n", ( void * )p );

    x = 10;
    p = &x;

    printf( "++p[0] = %d, ", ++p[0] );
    printf( "p = %p\n", ( void * )p );
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 10, p = 00ACF930
p++[0] = 10, p = 00ACF934
++p[0] = 11, p = 00ACF930
```

Comment: Is there a reason why someone would prefer `*(x + 1)` over `x[1]`?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride For example if you have a pointer p to a single object then the record  *p is preferable than p[0]

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride No, there is no reason for it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `*p` doesn't contain any pointer arithmetic so it's not really the same thing. Rather, if you have a pointer to a single object then `*p` is preferable to `p[0]` _and_ to `*(p+0)`.