# Understanding code looking like an int added to double array in (presumably) K&R C

Tags: c, syntax

I am trying to understand line 231 here:
https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gems/Roots3And4.c

Where it says `num += SolveQuadric(coeffs, s + num);` with `num` being an int and `s` looking to be an array of doubles.

The K&R assumption is because of the function declaration where after parenthesis and before the body curly bracket the type and size of the arrays are defined.

So if this really is an array and an int added, what is the outcome? The int added to every entry in the array? extending the array? or something completely different?

I am trying to port the code and I am not sure how to read this part.

Comment: `s + num` is equivalent to `&s[num]`. This isn't specific to K&R C, it's still true.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "pointer arithmetics"

Comment: If you are asking what pointer arithmetic is, then I'd suggest looking it up in a beginner-level C book... You should not have been assigned to the task of porting code if you are still a beginner.

Comment: While you are reading about the topic, you might take a look at this question: [why is a\[5\] == 5\[a\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a)

Comment: @Gerhardh Except that's just some "fun joke code". This one might be a bit more informative: [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num += SolveQuadric(coeffs, s + num);
```

where `s` double array and `num` is an integer.

`s + num` gives the reference of the `n`-th element of the array.