# Why can a pointer variable in c be written as p[i] (i is an integer)?

Tags: c

This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int a[3][3], *p, i;
    p = &a[0][0];
    for(i=0; i<9; i++) p[i]=i+1;
    printf("%d\n", a[1][2]);
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, I know the code will print 6. But since `p` is a pointer variable, how can it be written as `p[i]`. I guess that `p[i]` here is the same as `*(p+i)` and this will points to the `ith` element in the 2-dimension array. But my question is why are `p[i]` and `*(p+i)` the same if p is only a pointer variable?

PS: I know that if we define an array `a[10]`, `a` can be seen as a pointer constant.

Edited: I think my confusion lies in why the pointer can be indexed here.

I just wonder why this notation is acceptible in C?

Comment: The array indexing operator `[]` is nothing more than syntactic sugar.  The expression `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a+i)`.  So as you can see, it's commutative, so it's also equivalent to `i[a]`, although only a joker would write it that way.  If `a` is an array, it is converted to a pointer.  Then `i` is added, scaled appropriately.  The result is the address that the `*` operator is applied to (either reading or writing the location).

Comment: "why this notation is acceptible in C?" is a weird question.  It's acceptable because that's the specification.  More to your point, loosly, it's not that pointers can be indexed, it's that arrays are pointers and that's how you access an index.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a?rq=2 So, in this post, I notice that `a[b] = *(a + b)`, so in this equation, `a` and `b` can be any kind of variable, like pointer or integer.

Comment: @mendax1234 This was pointed out in the first comment.  The only requirement is that the sum `a+i` (from my example) be a valid data pointer that can be dereferenced.

Comment: @TomKarzes So, to make sum `a+i` a valid data pointer, at least `a` or `i` must be a pointer?

Comment: Strictly speaking `p` cannot use pointer arithmetic beyond the first inner `int[3]` array - doing so invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: This might be a more accurate duplicate [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing) I'd close as duplicate to that one, but I'm partial since I wrote the post. If @mendax1234 believes this link answers the question, I can close it though.

Comment: @mendax1234 One of them should be a data pointer, and the other should be some integer type.  Then it can perform pointer addition, scaling the integer by the size of the type pointed to, producing a new data pointer.

Comment: @TomKarzes Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Lundin I did that

Comment: @possum *it's that arrays are pointers*  **NO!!!** "Arrays are pointers" is confusing and not correct.  [Arrays are *not* "pointers"](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3): "an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object **and is not an lvalue.**" Pointers are variables (lvalues) that hold an address. That address may or may not be valid, and **it can change**. An array has an address. That address can't change - it is a location in memory it can't be assigned to.

Comment: (cont) Changing the number on your mailbox doesn't change where your house is.

Comment: hi @AndrewHenle There's a reason it was qualified with "loosely"

Comment: Re "*I guess that `p[i]` here is the same as `*(p+i)`*" `p[i]` is ALWAYS `*(p+i)`. If you pass an array, it decays into a pointer to its first element.