# Pass a 2d vector by reference

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

I read quite a few replies on this topic but still I can't get it.
Please understand I'm in a learning process.

I have been told that a vector is nothing else than its first element address so a 2D vector.

So, why do I lose the ability to use index if I pass a 2D vector by a pointer.

```
int vec[10][10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int *v = vec;
```

why I can't say

```
int a = v[1][1]
```

as I would do with

```
int a = vec[1][1]
```

if `v`, that is a pointer to an `int`, point exactly where `vec`, that is a pointer to an `int`, point, aren't they exactly the same thing, the same object?

I read about

```
int (*v)[N] = vec;
```

where `N` is the number of columns.
But this appears as a super tricky thing for a beginner.

Why is this?

**EDIT**:

My brains came up this explanation for `int (*vec)[N]` meaning *a pointer to a vector of 10 `int`*.
Here it is.

Giving I understood that in a 2D array, a pointer to the first element is a pointer to an array of `N` elements, this is the explanation I gave myself.

If lhs of `int *var = &int` have to be read right to left, becoming "`var` is `a pointer` to `int`" then I would expect that `int [N] * var = &2darray` would be, right to left, "var is a pointer to an array of N int elements".

But this is syntactically incorrect to the compiler so I have to do the trick `int (* vec) [N] = 2darray` that, right to left, keeping in mind parenthesis priority become:

Parenthesis first, right to left: `vec` is `a pointer`.

Then the rest, that now is, right to left: `int [N]`.

The final result is `vec` is `a pointer` to `an array of N` of `int`.

Have this even remotely any sense?

Comment: `vec` can decay to a pointer to its first element. I.e. `vec` could be the same as `&vec[0]`, which has the type `int (*)[10]`. What `vec` definitely isn't, is a pointer to a single `int`. The expression `v[1][1]` requires `v` to be either an array of arrays, or a pointer to an array.

Comment: C does not have vectors, it has arrays, and arrays are _not_ pointers despite that many folks will wrongly say that they are. Arrays are independent types which decay to pointers to their first elements in most circumstances.

Comment: Re “I have been said that a vector is nothing else that its first element address…”: That is false.

Comment: What I can't handle is that when I create a pointer I'm giving just another name to the same object, it appears to me. So it seems strange that then I can't treat the object the same way just because I'm using another name to refer to it.

Comment: @atpaul, Yes, you are effectively _aliasing_ that object.  The difference stays in tha you can make your pointer to point to another, different object, of the same characteristics, by just assigning the pointer a different object's address.  In this manner the alias allows you to refer to _any_ object of the same type, and not only the one you used when you initialized it...

Comment: ... In C, this is very important, as it allows you to actually pass objects _by reference_ and not only by value.  Just pass the address of the object to be used as a function parameter and your function will be able to act on any object of a fixed type, by just passing the address of the actual object you want to act upon.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler should issue a message that in this declaration

```
int* v = vec;
```

there is used a pointer of incompatible pointer type to initialize the pointer `v` of the type `int *`.

The array `vec` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. The type of elements of this two dimensional array is `int[10]`. So a pointer to elements of the array will have the type `int ( * )[10]`.

You may not use an expression like that `v[1][1]` in your code snippet becuase the sub-expression `v[1]` has the type `int`. That is the sub-expression `v[1]` produces a scalar object that is not an array. So such an expression `v[1][1]` is just invalid.

If you will write

```
int vec[10][10] = {1,2,3,4};
int ( *v )[10] = vec;
```

then  the sub-expression `v[1]` yields an object of the type `int[10]` that is an array. So you may apply one more the subscript operator to the obtained array like `v[1][1]`.

Pay attention to that if you have a one dimensional array like for example

```
int a[n];
```

then elements of this array have the type `int`. And the array used in expressions with rare exceptions (as for example using in `sizeof` operator) is converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `int *`.

On the other hand, if you have a two-dimensional array like

```
int a[m][n];
```

then elements of the array are one-dimensional arrays of the type `int[n]` and a pointer to elements of the array has the type `int ( * )[n]`.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the C language design revolves around arrays decaying to a pointer to the first element whenever used in most expressions. The `[]` operator was designed around such an assumption - it actually cannot use an array as operand, it always uses a pointer. See [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55747822/584518)

And that pointer parameter handed to the `[]` operator results in pointer arithmetic on the de-referenced type. Given `int* ptr;` then `ptr[n]` performs pointer arithmetic on items of type `int`.

So for a plain array `int vec[10]` we can write `int* ptr = vec;` and that's fine since `vec` decays into a pointer to its first element here.

`int vec[10][10];` ... `int* v = vec;` is however invalid C. The first element of `int [10][10]` is a `int [10]`. So then `vec` decays, it decays into a pointer to an `int [10]`, which is written as `int (*)[10]`. This type is not compatible with `int*` so the code posted violates assignment constraints and the compiler must issue a diagnostic message here.

In case when we are typing `vec[n]`, `vec` decays to a `int(*)[10]` and we therefore get pointer arithmetic on items of `int [10]` type.

Now regarding the pointer to array syntax, a pointer to the array `int vec[10][10]` would be declared as `int (*ptr)[10][10]`. When we already have a pointer rather than array, there is no such thing as decay, so `ptr[n]` would actually give us the *nth* array item of type `int [10][10]`... which is not helpful, we do not have an array of `int [10][10]` items. To actually get to a `int [10]` item which is more likely what we want, we would first have to de-reference the pointer: `(*ptr)[n]`. Rather cumbersome syntax.

Therefore the convenient trick is to declare the pointer one dimension short: `int (*ptr)[10]`. This corresponds directly to an array `int vec[n][10]`. We can use `ptr[i][j]` to access the `int` item in the 2D array. Or we can do `vec[i][j]` in which case `vec` decays and we also get an `int` item in the 2D array.

Comment: I have to dive deep into this reply, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Arrays in C language are not vectors.
2. Multi dimensional arrays in `C` are arrays of arrays

```
int x[2][3]
```

Defines two elements array of arrays of 3 `int` elements.

3. Arrays in C decay to pointer to its first element when they are used as lvalues (ie in expressions)

- `x` from p.2 decays to pointer to array of 3 `int` elements.
- `x[0]' decays to pointer to` int`

4. You need to use pointers to arrays (it is nothing special). It is a pointer which has a type of array.

```
int (*p)[3];
```

defines `p` as pointer to array of 3 int elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
char c[10], *pc = c;
int i[10], *pi = i, ii[10][10], (*pii)[10] = ii;
```

`char` takes 1 byte and `int` takes 4 bytes in memory.

```
pc ++;
pi ++;
```

`pc` now is pointing to c[1], pi now is pointing to p[1].
There's nothing complicated here, if you look a little closer, the `++` operator for these two statements do different job under the hood.
`pc` is a pointer to char and the value of pc is increased by `1` in order to point to the next char, however, `pi` is a pointer to int, thus is increased by `4` in order to point to the next int. You can see these by printing them.

```
printf("before pc: %x, after pc: %x", pc - 1, pc);
printf("before pi: %x, after pi: %x", pi - 1, pi); // the printed values will show you what I am saying
```

And it's time to look at `pii` which is a pointer to `int[10]`.

```
pii ++;  // internally, the value of pii is increased by 40, which is `10 * sizeof(int)`
pii[0] // ii[1][0]
pii[3] // ii[1][3]

pii += 2  // value of pii is increased by 80
pii[0] // ii[3][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

> why I can't say

```
int a = v[1][1]
```

Because `v` is a pointer to `int`, you can only access an element, using a single access `[]` operator, not two.  Had you declared it correctly, then you will be able to do:

```
int (*v)[10] = vec;
```

then you can use correctly `v[1][1]` or even `v[9][9]`, as now v is a pointer to an array of ten arrays of 10 integers.

The problem here is that, when you say just `vec` the C language interprets it as *a pointer to the first element* (with a type of pointer to the accessed data)  **which is also an array**, so it decays (again) into a pointer to the first element, this is a pointer to `int`.

Even, you can use a pointer to the full thing:

```
int (*v)[10][10] = &vec;
```

but the, you have to use the address of the 2D array.  That's valid too.

#### Note:

The parenthesis are necessary, as `v` must be a pointer to an array, and not an array of pointers (which it should be if you have not used them)

Comment: I clearly understand what to do to pass a 2darray. Now I have just to understand why I have to do so lol, thanks for your reply, I have to study a lot this topic.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the other answers, `int *v = vec;` is a type mismatch and should generate a diagnostic.  Compiling with advanced warnings and making these warnings errors is a good practice to try and avoid mistakes that lead to undefined behavior or other bugs.

Use **gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror** or use the same flags for **clang**.

As stated in your question, the correct definition is:

```
int (*v)[10] = vec;
```

To decipher such definitions, you should study and use the [spiral rule](https://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: Spiral rule, interesting. But It would give me:

"v is an [array of 10] pointers to int". 

And it is not, right. It is a pointer to an array of 10.

Comment: @ATpaul: no, `int (*v)[10]` gives: `v` is a pointer to array(s) of 10 `int`.  The parentheses around `(*v)` force the *is a pointer* before *is an array*.