# Pointers to Character Array

Tags: c

So I am in the process of learning C and am slightly confused by this statement on the website I am learning from.

if you have

```
char ch_arr[3][10] = {
                         "spike",
                         "tom",
                         "jerry"
                     };
```

It says that.

> The `ch_arr` is a pointer to an array of 10 characters or `int(*)[10]`

However, what is the meaning of `int(*)[10]`, if this is a character array, why is the pointer not a char type?

Thanks in advance, sorry if the question is bad, I'm trying to get better at asking questions.

Comment: What's the web site? A pointer to an array of 10 characters is of type `char(*)[10]`, not `int(*)[10]`. Could be a typo on the site.

Comment: Hello, the website and specific page I am looking at is here https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/array-of-strings-in-c/

Comment: "ch_arr is a pointer " -->. No, `ch_arr` is an array. [array 3 of array 10 of char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+ch_arr%5B3%5D%5B10%5D+).  Pointer are not arrays.  Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: But isn't the name of an array a pointer to the first element in C?

Comment: To be precise, the object named `ch_arr` is an object of array type (and saying it's a pointer is misleading) -- however the *expression* `ch_arr` is, in most but not all contexts, treated as a pointer expression. See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Worth reading on [arrays and pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868367/whats-a-modern-term-for-array-pointer-equivalence).

Comment: @Sekken No, it's "converted" to a pointer in most but not all contexts. For example, `sizeof ch_arr` yields the size of the array object, not the size of a pointer. See the link in my previous comment. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: I believe I understand now, thank you for these resources they are wonderful and I will check them out, thank you all for quick responses and helping me out!

Comment: See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). Array/Pointer conversion applies to the first dimension of every array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two-dimensional array. Each string (e.g. "spike") is a character array. That means that it's basically an array containing arrays.

```
char ch_arr[3][10] = {"spike", "tom", "jerry"};
```

The two-dimensional array `ch_arr` can then be *converted* to a pointer. In both C and C++ array to pointer conversion [applies to every array automatically on access](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3), so the pointer points to the first element, which is of type `char[10]` in this case. Therefore the pointer is of type `char(*)[10]`, as [Keith Thoumpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) pointed out in the comments.

And concerning the website you are using... It contains some mistakes, so I would use a different source instead.

Comment: Hello, thanks, I understand what a 2D array is however  int(*)[10] this syntax is quite confusing, could you explain to me what it is saying in english? Thanks

Comment: Array/Pointer conversion applies to every array automatically on access. See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3).

Comment: cdecl is a useful resource, either https://cdecl.org/ or the application. For example, `declare foo as pointer to array 10 of char` gives you `char (*foo)[10]`. Drop the identifier to get the type name: `char (*)[10]`, which means "pointer to array 10 of `char`".

Comment: And remember that a 2D array is nothing more or less than an array of arrays.

Comment: @KeithThompson that's exactly what I wrote: _That means that it's basically an array containing arrays._

Comment: Yes, but the point being is array/pointer conversion applies not only to `ch_arr`, but also to `ch_arr[i]`.