# Index of pointer

Tags: c, pointers

In the code below I set the variable `var` to 20, then the pointer `ptr` to the address of `var`. Then the pointer `ptrptr` to hold the memory address of the pointer `ptr`.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

void pointers()
{
    int var = 20;
    int* ptr;
    ptr = &var;

    int *ptrptr = ptr;

    printf("Value at ptrptr[0] = %d \n", ptrptr[0]);
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
    pointers();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Value at ptrptr[0] = 20
```

Why does `ptrptr[0]` return the value stored by `val`, and not the memory address of the pointer `ptr`.

I thought that the indexing operator `[]` returns the value stored by that value.

Comment: there is no `val` in the code

Comment: `ptrptr` and `ptr` are both of the same type and hold the same value - the address of `var`. If you want `ptrptr` to hold the address of `ptr` you need another level of indirection: `int **ptrptr = &ptr;`.

Comment: Just because you name something `ptrptr`, it doesn't become a pointer to pointer. I'll assume that `int *ptrptr` was just a typo, you meant `int **ptrptr` and we can therefore close this as 'simple typo'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example which will, I hope, make it more clear what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int var = 20;
    int *ptr = &var;
    int *ptr2 = ptr;

    printf("the value of the variable var is %d\n", var);
    printf("the address of the variable var is %p\n\n", &var);

    printf("the value of the pointer ptr is %p\n", ptr);
    printf("the value pointed to by ptr is %d\n", *ptr);
    printf("or, stated another way, it's %d\n\n", ptr[0]);

    printf("the value of the pointer ptr2 is %p\n", ptr2);
    printf("the value pointed to by ptr2 is %d\n", *ptr2);
}
```

On my machine this prints:

```
the value of the variable var is 20
the address of the variable var is 0x7ffeed56992c

the value of the pointer ptr is 0x7ffeed56992c
the value pointed to by ptr is 20
or, stated another way, it's 20

the value of the pointer ptr2 is 0x7ffeed56992c
the value pointed to by ptr2 is 20
```

Since `ptr` and `ptr2` have the same type (`int *`), and since they hold the same pointer value (since we said `ptr2 = ptr`), they behave the same.

And because of the "correspondence between arrays and pointers" in C, `*ptr` is identical to `ptr[0]`.  Both expressions yield the value pointed to by `ptr`.

If your intention with `ptrptr` was to have it be a pointer to a pointer, here's an illustration of that wrinkle.  Since `ptrptr` is a two-level pointer, its pointed-to value is actually another pointer, so you have to be really careful thinking about it.

```
int **ptrptr = &ptr;
printf("the value of the pointer ptrptr is %p\n", ptrptr);
printf("the value pointed to by ptrptr is %p\n", *ptrptr);
printf("and the value pointed to by that pointer is %d\n", **ptrptr);
```

This additionally prints:

```
the value of the pointer ptrptr is 0x7ffeed569920
the value pointed to by ptrptr is 0x7ffeed56992c
and the value pointed to by that pointer is 20
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when you say the "correspondence between arrays and pointers" what is meant by this. Are they any resources that explain this further, I am a beginner.

Comment: @DylanDijk The "correspondence between arrays and pointers" is a [new term I devised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868367#48887033) which has not really caught on yet.  The older wording was "equivalence between arrays and pointers", but that term is deprecated now.  Another term is "array to pointer decay".

Comment: The two main parts of this principle are that (a) when you mention an array in an expression, as if to take its value, what you get (the value you get) is actually a pointer to the array's first element, as if you had written `&a[0]`, and (b) the array-subscripting operator `a[i]` is defined as (is precisely equivalent to) `*(a + i)`.

Comment: Any proper textbook or tutorial or other instructional material on C should explain this, usually in a section called "arrays and pointers".  (Some, though, explain it better than others, and unfortunately, some of the explanations out there are really bad.  In particular, if you come across an "explanation" that says something like "an array is a constant pointer to its first element", stop reading and find a better tutorial.)

Answer (score 4):

By definition `*(ptr + n) === ptr[n]`

> Why does ptrptr[0] return the value stored by val, and not the memory
> address of the pointer ptr.
>
> I thought that the indexing operator [] returns the value stored by
> that value.

no `ptr[x]` dereferences the pointer.

```
int x = 5;
int *ptr = &x;
int *ptrptr = ptr; //this assigns reference stored in ptr to ptrptr. Now they store the same reference.

printf("Dereferencing pointer - %d\n", ptr[0]);
printf("Reference stored in the pointer - %p\n", (void *)ptr);
printf("Reference of the pointer (its address) - %p\n", (void *)&ptr);
```

Judging from the name of your second pointer you probably wanted pointer to pointer

```
int x = 5;
int *ptr = &x;
int **ptrptr = &ptr; //poiter to pointer

printf("Dereferencing pointer to pointer - reference of x %p\n", (void *)ptrptr[0]);
printf("Reference stored in the pointer to pointer - reference of ptr%p\n", (void *)ptrptr);
printf("Reference of the pointer (its address) - %p\n", (void *)&ptrptr);
```

Comment: When you say "By definition `*(ptr + n) === ptr[n]`" what does adding an integer to a pointer do?

Comment: Also where can such definitions that you have given be found. Are they in some documentation?

Comment: @DylanDijk this documentation is called "C standard". Google it: "C standard pdf"

Comment: @DylanDijk by definition -> because it is defined this way in the C standard which is **the only** source of C. No websites, YT videos or tutorials

Answer (score 3):

This

```
ptrptr[0]
```

is the same as (because `ptrptr` and `ptr` are same type and have same value):

```
ptr[0]
```

is the same as (because `a[b] == *(a+b)`):

```
*ptr
```

is the same as `var`, because `ptr` points to `var`, and `*ptr` is dereferencing the pointer.

The value of `var` is `20`.

Answer (score 2):

`ptrptr` has the same type as `ptr`, a pointer to an `int`. So when you do `int *ptrptr = ptr;`, now `ptrptr` and `ptr` point to the same address (that's why it compiles as well). Also `ptrptr[0]` is the same as to `*ptrptr`

You have to define `ptrptr` to be a pointer to a pointer of an `int`:

```
int **ptrptr = &ptr;
printf("Value at ptrptr[0] = %d \n", *ptrptr[0]);
```

if you wanted `ptrptr` to point to `ptr`

[Link to Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4dGnErr4W).

Answer (score 1):

You never set *ptrptr* to hold the memory address of *ptr* but to the value of *ptr* itself. Below is an image for illustration. First *ptr* is assigned the address of *var* and then *ptrptr* is assigned the value of *ptr*, so it also points to *var*.

[image: equal pointers]

To make *ptrptr* point to *ptr* you need to declare it as

```
int **ptrptr = &ptr;
```

[image: pointer to pointer]