# How do the pointers work in the following block of code?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand how pointers work and I am stuck on this block of code. Can someone explain where does the expression '*(a+tally)' point to in this block of code? What is the logic behind it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5},b[5]={10,20,30,40,50},tally;
    
    for(tally=0;tally< 5;++tally)
    {
        *(a+tally)= *(tally+a) + *(b+tally);
    }
    
    for(tally=0;tally< 5;tally++) 
    {
        printf("%d" *(a+tally));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is this easier to read?  `a[tally] += b[tally];`

Comment: Related: [Are arrays in C a syntactic sugar for pointers? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851598/are-arrays-in-c-a-syntactic-sugar-for-pointers)

Comment: The expression `*(a+tally)` does not point to anything.  The expression `a + tally` is the address of an element of `a`, and `*(a + tally)` is the object at that address.  `a` has 5 elements. `a + 0` is the address of the first, `a + 1` is the address of the next, etc.  `a + (i - 1)` is the address of the ith element.  So `a + 4` is address of the 5th element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example this expression

```
*(a+tally)
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
a[tally]
```

and yields the (lvalue) element of the array at index `tally`.

As a result this loop

```
for(tally=0;tally< 5;++tally)
{
    *(a+tally)= *(tally+a) + *(b+tally);
}
```

is equivalent to the following loop

```
for(tally=0;tally< 5;++tally)
{
    a[tally] = a[tally] + b[tally];
}
```

That is the expression

```
a + tally
```

or the equivalent expression

```
tally + a
```

points to the element of the array `a` with the index equal to the value of `tally`.

Pay attention that as the expression `a[tally]` is calculated like `*( a + tally )` or as `*( tally + a )` (due to the commutative nature of the addition) then the expression `a[tally]` may be rewritten also like `tally[a]`.

Comment: `tally[a]`  : I never seen this before, it's so strange.. Thanks for the info anyway !