# Incompatible pointer type warning re pointer to array of int pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote the following code declaring an array of 5 pointers to int and then a pointer to the address of the mentioned array:

```
int* arr[5];
int** p=&arr;
```

At compilation with gcc, I get the following warning:

> initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>      int** p=&arr;

Why is `int** p` the wrong pointer type, isn't `&arr` a pointer to a pointer to an `int`?

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C, are arrays pointers or used as pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers)

Comment: You were probably told arrays are pointers in disguise. You were told an oversimplification. Arrays are not pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the statement

```
int* arr[5];
```

`arr` is array of `5` int pointer. Let's say it's pointing to `a` which is array of `5` integer. It looks like

```
int a[5]=  {1,2,3,4,5};
int* arr[5] = {a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
```

Now when you write

```
int** p=&arr;
```

which is wrong as  `p` is of `int**` type and it should point to `arr` not to `&arr`.

*isn't &arr a pointer to a pointer to an int?* No, it's not, **`&arr`** is **pointer to an array of pointers to int `a[0]` etc**.

Correct way is

```
int **p= arr;
```

Now you can print the array `a` elements using `p` as

```
printf("%d %d\n",*p[0],*p[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

change `int **p = &arr` to either `int **p = &arr[0]` or `int **p = arr`

In the second option array name `arr` is converted to a pointer to its first element arr[0] (i.e. a pointer to a pointer to an int).

Answer (score -4):

int* arr[5] is a pointer to a pointer to an int, so &arr is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int.

Comment: `int* arr[5]` is not a pointer to a pointer. It is an array of pointers. So `&arr` is a pointer to an array of pointers to int.