# Why do I get different results for "a+1" and "&a+1" in a 2d array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[3][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    clrscr();    
    printf("%u \n",a);
    printf("%u, %u\n", a+1, &a+1);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
> 65502
> 65510
> 65526

How does this program work if `sizeof(int)=2` and base address is `65502`?

Comment: Because `a+1` means add `1` `sizeof *a` to `a`, and `&a+1` means add `1` `sizeof a` to `&a`. `sizeof *a` is `sizeof (int[4])`; `sizeof a` is `sizeof (int[3][4])`

Comment: Printing a pointer with `%u` is undefined behavior.

Comment: I think this will help you the most.  Give it a read. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608421/10758654

Answer (score 1):

When you use an array like `a` in an expression, it usually goes through “pointer decay” which means that you get a pointer to the first element of the array.

So, `a` has type `int[3][4]`, and it decays to `int (*)[4]`. When you write `a+1`, you get the address of `a[1]`… which is `sizeof(*a)` bytes after `a`, which is `sizeof(int)*4`, which is 8 on your system.

When you use `&`, pointer decay does not happen. `&a` is not an array (it is already a pointer), so when you write `&a+1`, you get the address “one past the end” of `a`… which is `sizeof(a)` bytes after a, which is `sizeof(int)*12`, or 24 bytes on your system.

Note that, strictly speaking, the correct way to print pointers is with `%p`.

```
printf("%p\n", a);
printf("%p, %p\n", a+1, &a+1);
```

(Technically, you also have to cast to `char *` or `void *` but that’s hardly ever important.)

Answer (score 0):

When you increment a pointer, it gets incremented in steps of the **object size that the pointer can point to**.

Type of `a` is `int (*)[4]`<sup>1)</sup> i.e. pointer to an object which is an array of `4` `int` type. So, the `a + 1` will be a pointer obtained by adding size of array of `4` integers to pointer evaluated from `a` in the expression.

Type of `&a` is `int (*)[3][4]`<sup>1)</sup> i.e. pointer to an object which is a 2D array of `int` type with dimension `3x4`. So, the `&a + 1` will be a pointer obtained by adding size of 2D array of integers with dimension `3x4` to pointer evaluated from `&a` in the expression.

---

1. When you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to first element (there are few [exceptions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) to this rule).

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%u, %u\n", a+1, &a+1);
```

- `a+1` - Here `a` decays into a pointer to its first element. In this case a pointer to an array of `4` `int` (type `int (*)[4]`).  Have a look at [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12139179) for more information.

  Thereafter you increment this pointer by one. So, now the gained address is the one of one array element of `4` `int` of the 2D array forward, which matches to your output as `sizeof(int) == 2` * `4` = `8`. The difference between `65502` and `65510` is `8`.

  ---
- `&a+1` - `&a` is first evaluated. When the `&` operator is applied, `a` doesn't decay to a pointer to its first element. Rather `&a` gains a pointer to the whole 2D array/ a pointer to an array of 3 arrays of 4 `int` (type `int (*)[3][4]`).

  Incrementing this pointer by one gets you one the size of the whole 2D array forward which also matches to your output because the difference between `65502` `65526` is `24` which is correct because `sizeof(int) == 2` * (`3 * 4`) = `24`. `(3 * 4)` is the amount of elements in the 2D array.

---

**Note**: Printing a pointer with the `%u` format specifier invokes strictly seen [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984). You need the `%p` format specifier for pointers and need to cast the pointer argument to `void *` to be standard-compliant.

```
printf("%p\n", (void*) a);
printf("%p, %p\n", (void*) a+1, (void*) &a+1);
```

- [Correct format specifier to print pointer or address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/12139179)