# need to get size for CString array in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have method which receives `CString SearchString[]` in C++

I would like to get the size of this array to iterate in for loop, if not then could someone suggest how to convert this array to `CStringArray`.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void myFunction(HWND shwnd, CString SearchString[], BOOl Visible)
{
    //how do i get the size of "SearchString" here;
   // I do not know how much it is populated, there might be one, two or three strings
}

int main()
{
    CString Header[12];
    BOOL bVisible;
    myFunction(shwnd,Header,bVisible);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about `size_t` ??? w..w... wait are you asking for code?

Comment: I do not know the size of the receiving array, i need to get that

Comment: Make it a template that deduces the size, pass the size, or use `std::array`.

Comment: Question is confusing , why would you want to convert an Cstringarray back to an Cstring array ? .Do you want to convert a charecter string to Cstring array ?

Comment: @Santhosh: void abc(HWND shwnd, CString searchString[], BOOl visible)

my method is like this, now i need to find the size of this "searchString"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of static array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453099/size-of-static-array)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a function template to get a handle on the size of any fixed size array:

```
template<size_t N >
void foo( CString (&SearchString)[N] )
{
  // the length of the array is N
}
```

So, you could make your function a template:

```
template<size_t N >
void myFunction(HWND shwnd, CString (&SearchString)[N], BOOl Visible)
{
   // the length of SearchString is N in here
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    CString Header[12];
    BOOL bVisible; // you might need to initialize this
    myFunction(shwnd, Header, bVisible);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can give some code , it will be helpful to understand and give your answer. From your question I guess you have a array of strings and you want to know the size of it. You can use STL vector where you can use string data type and can easily find the size of the vector. I am giving a sample code which can help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void myfunction(vector<string>& searchstring)
{
    int a=searchstring.size();
    cout<<a;
}
int main()
{
    vector<string>searchstring;
    searchstring.push_back("hi");
    searchstring.push_back("hello");
    searchstring.push_back("man");
    searchstring.push_back("man");
    myfunction(searchstring);
    searchstring.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

here the size of the vector is 4.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you change the signature of the function(s)?

Then you can use `CStringArray` or `vector<CString>` which instantly become easier to use?

```
void myFunction(HWND hwnd, CStringArray stringArray, BOOL Visible)
{
  for(int nIndex = 0; nIndex < stringArray.GetSize(); nIndex++)
  {
    CString tempString(stringArray.GetAt(nIndex));
    // do something with string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300471%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to get the length of an Cstring object using an function called as  **GetLength**.

Comment: Santosh, you are not getting my question, i do not want string length of each item in the array. I need the array size

Comment: Try using sizeof function to get the sizeof array , i couldn't try this on my system as i don't have visual studio at present.

Comment: I believe "sizeof" can be used on CStringArray, not on CString abc[]

Comment: Getlength usually gives the number of bytes in the cstring object as per the msdn documentation . That itself is the size .You can even convert cstring object to an regular null terminated string and then calculate the size of the string array .

Comment: @SanthoshPai `sizeof` will not work inside of a plain function, because the type of the array will decay to a pointer. All size information is lost after this. So you need to pass the size as a parameter, or use a function template as I showed.